Google Analytics 4 custom events are not being sent
I'm implementing GA4 on a site. The code looks like this:
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-K..."></script>
    <script>
      console.log(window.dataLayer)
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', 'G-K...');
      gtag('event', 'testing', { 'start': 'true' })
    </script>

What I see in the network tab is one 'collect' request at load, and another a few seconds later.

Adding further event calls never triggers an actual network request.
I'm using Safari for this testing with no privacy features, so it's not that network requests are being blocked.
Is there another explanation for why the event call is not doing anything?
If I set I set up debug mode, the events trigger network activity and show up correctly in TagAssistant:

But as soon as I leave debug mode, they stop working.
What do I need to do?
